# How to change the background color of Eclipse's "Packages" tab

Tags: eclipse, ide

How do I change the background color of Eclipse's Packages tab? It's too bright and is slightly distracting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can think of it, as a composite step, if you want to change only the packages tab color. First of all you can go to marketplace (Help/Marketplace) and find a theme that fulfills your needs(you can choose also a pre-installed themes from Eclipse Eclipse menu -> Window -> Preference -> General). Install and apply it. If you are happy with that theme, in the code editor too, you are done. But if you want your code editor to remain the same, go to Eclipse menu -> Window -> Preference -> General -> Appearance -> Color Theme and choose the editor's theme you used to use. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Appearance` -> `Colors and Fonts` .

Then in the `View and Editor Folders` section , mainly playing with the following options to configure them :

- Active part background begin
- Active part background end
- Active part foreground

And possibly playing with the following options too :

- Active part (non-focus) background begin
- Active part (non-focus) background end
- Active part (non-focus) foreground